# Where Can if find the NSBundle in the applicaton for an ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, mobile, ios8

I am running a template of an app. I want to be able to change the contents of the NSBundle, which include a list of names. How would I be able to find from this source?

let paths = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType(
            "png", inDirectory: nil) as! [String]

```
    // get image filenames from paths
    for path in paths {
        if !path.lastPathComponent.hasPrefix("AppIcon") {
            allCountries.append(path.lastPathComponent)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this code
NSURL *rtfUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"paylines" withExtension:@".txt"];
```